# Python list of tuples to dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, defaultdict

There is a python list

```
[('schema1', 'table1', 'column_name1'), ('schema1', 'table1', 'column_name2'), ('schema1', 'table2', 'column_name3'), ('schema2', 'table3', 'column_name4')]
```

I need to convert it into python dict with the following structure

```
schema1:
            table1:
                    (column_name1,
                    column_name2)
            table2:
                    (column_name3)
schema2:
            table3:
                    (column_name4)
```

Are there any efficient ways to convert?

Comment: Post some code showing what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do this with a [**`defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) that produces `defaultdict(list)` instances as default values.

**Demo**

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
>>> data = [('schema1', 'table1', 'column_name1'), ('schema1', 'table1', 'column_name2'), ('schema1', 'table2', 'column_name3'), ('schema2', 'table3', 'column_name4')]
>>> 
>>> for k1, k2, v in data:
...:    d[k1][k2].append(v)
...:    
>>> d
>>> 
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>()>,
            {'schema1': defaultdict(list,
                         {'table1': ['column_name1', 'column_name2'],
                          'table2': ['column_name3']}),
             'schema2': defaultdict(list, {'table3': ['column_name4']})})
```

To match your desired output exactly (although I don't see much reason), build a regular dictionary from `d` with `tuple` values.

```
>>> d = {k1:{k2:tuple(v2) for k2, v2 in v1.items()} for k1, v1 in d.items()}
>>> d
>>> 
{'schema1': {'table1': ('column_name1', 'column_name2'),
  'table2': ('column_name3',)},
 'schema2': {'table3': ('column_name4',)}}
```

**Explanation**

The `defaultdict` initializer accepts a callable (in this example an anonymous `lambda` function is used). Whenever a key is missing, that callable is called and the return value is used as a fallback-value.

The line

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
```

is creating a `defaultdict` which creates another `defaultdict` when a key is missing. The second defaultdict creates a `list` when a key is missing.

```
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
>>> d['bogus']
>>> defaultdict(list, {})
>>> d['hokus']['pokus']
>>> []
```

Answer (score 6):

Sure. Use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for schema, table, colname in L:
    dd[schema][table].append(colname)
```

Result:

```
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {'schema1': defaultdict(list,
                         {'table1': ['column_name1', 'column_name2'],
                          'table2': ['column_name3']}),
             'schema2': defaultdict(list, {'table3': ['column_name4']})})
```

Comment: this is rather elegant, i have not used this particular pattern before

Comment: @Chris_Rands, I sense sarcasm :)

Comment: No I don't think @Chris_Rands knew this was a duplicate ;-)

Answer (score 3):

No need for any special things, simple dictionary methods work:

```
d = [('schema1', 'table1', 'column_name1'), 
     ('schema1', 'table1', 'column_name2'), 
     ('schema1', 'table2', 'column_name3'), 
     ('schema2', 'table3', 'column_name4')]

k = {}

for schema,table,column in d:
    p =  k.setdefault(schema,{})
    p2 = p.setdefault(table,[])
    p2.append(column)

print(k)
```

Output:

```
{'schema1': {'table2': ['column_name3'], 
             'table1': ['column_name1', 'column_name2']}, 
 'schema2': {'table3': ['column_name4']}}
```

---

Although more experienced ppl suggest not using this, because its slower. So it is better to work with the defaultdict-approach provided by the other answers.

Comment: what's wrong with an `import` of `defaultdict`? it will likely be more performant too

Comment: @Chris_Rands nothing is wrong with defaultdicts - but 2 other answers already used those - and its not needed. As for performace - I dont know which would be faster/better. One would have to test that.

Comment: Re:Performance, `setdefault` is slower because the default is _always_ created, even if the key exists (even though it isn't used in that situation). In the case of a defaultdict, it's better.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [('schema1', 'table1', 'column_name1'), ('schema1', 'table1', 'column_name2'), 
 ('schema1', 'table2', 'column_name3'), ('schema2', 'table3', 'column_name4')]
d = {}

for s, t, c in l:
    d[s] = d.get(s, {})
    d[s][t] = d[s].get(t, tuple()) + (c,)
print(d)
```

Out put:

```
{'schema1': {'table1': ('column_name1', 'column_name2'), 
             'table2': ('column_name3',)}, 
 'schema2': {'table3': ('column_name4',)}}
```